# Can/Should I copy a system partition to a new SSD?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, ssd

I've installed Windows 7 on one of the partitions of my laptop's secondary HD.
I've decided to purchase a solid state drive (SSD) to replace my primary drive.

Can I just copy the entire partition to the new SSD, using a tool like Paragon Partition Manager, or any of the others out there, or am I'm doomed to re-install, the OS, re-install all my software, re-arrange all the settings again, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up re-installing the entire system, but keeping the old partition as a backup. I now have a dual-boot machine (both Win7) that share a documents directory.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this may work for you, but why not try imaging your laptop?? Make an image of how you want windows to be like after installation burn it to a DVD and then install from there?? Technically you are not freshly installing!
Not sure of the process, my professors do it at school for every computer to run a modified version of XP.

Comment: Actually, that's what I meant (image=full copy of one or more partitions). I want to image the Windows 7 partition - but I'm not sure if I can then put that image on an SSD.